# Looking up names in a data.frame with partial matching, need them sorted

Tags: r

I want to look up indexes of variables in a `data.frame` given a chain of (partial) variable names. An example:

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("az","bz","cz"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now I have a chain given as:

```
v <- c("a > b")
```

I'm now searching the *sorted* corresponding variable names in the `data.frame`.

I do this with:

```
df$var[grep(paste(trimws(unlist(strsplit(v, ">"))), collapse = "|"), df$var)]
[1] "az" "bz"
```

This works in the first example. For the second example this fails:

```
v <- c("b > a")
df$var[grep(paste(trimws(unlist(strsplit(v, ">"))), collapse = "|"), df$var)]
[1] "az" "bz"
```

It returns `[1] "az" "bz"`, whereas **I expect `[1] "bz" "az"`.**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't do it via regex (`b|a`) and leave them as a vector as that is derived from your `strsplit()` function, i.e. `c(2,1)`, then by looping and using `grep`, you get the correct order, i.e.

```
df$var[sapply(trimws(unlist(strsplit(v, ">"))), function(i)grep(i, df$var))]
#[1] "bz" "az"
```